# LibreOffice Calc: How to make AutoFilter changes permanent?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

When I apply an AutoFilter to my LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet, it's natural to have some rows removed, like in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPb5b.png). However, it's been clunky dealing with it, and I don't like this behavior to perpetuate. How can I have LibreOffice Calc apply the changes in the AutoFilter permanently, so there is no going back, and the rows start numbering correctly again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will always see the numbering after applying AutoFilter as there are still other rows on the sheets. There are just hidden due to the autofiltering; there are not removed. So LibreOffice Calc (or Excel or Google Sheets, etc.) will show the cells' row numbers the data are in.

If you want the rows also auto numbered, you have to either:

- Copy the auto-filtered data to another sheet or
- Add a a new column after you have applied the filter. Insert 1 on the first cell with data, then insert the formula `=SUBTOTAL(2,B$2:$B2)+1` on the next cell. Drag it down to fill the other cells. Column B here os just an example, you will need to adapt it.

Comment: Dang it. I definitely see what you mean. Is this the case with standard filters as well? If not, I'll be using SFs from now on, AutoFilter can be a pain, esp. when copying and pasting, I'd get the whole unfiltered list. Option 1 in your post seems like the easiest thing I can do. Thank you.

Comment: When the data is a range, the row are renumbered after you filter them. With a table, there are not.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer: You can select the entire spreadsheet (or `Edit->Select Data Area`), click `Edit->Select Visible Rows Only`, copy **that**, select e.g. cell A1 **only in another Sheet or spreadsheet**, and then paste.